# Avoid pressing Right+Left and Up+Down when using Input.GetAxisRaw

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using this simple piece of code bellow to move a [RigidBody2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody2D.html) object through the scene.
It works very well when I use a joystick, but if I use the keyboard and press Right+Left or A+D, at the same time, the result of `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` will be `0`, and the object will not move (same thing on the vertical direction).

```
void Move()
{
  _rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized * speed;
}
```

The expected behavior should be:

If I'm moving the object to the right and press the left key (while holding the right key), I wish that the left key will be ignored and the object will keep moving to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this system:

```
if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0)
 {
   //move to the right
 }
else if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0){ 
// move to the left }
```

Since the GetAxisRaw can be only -1, 0, 1 with this system only one will be taken at the time, so if you start pressing `right` and then `left` it will only move to the right and the same for reverse inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to handle the validation of the input yourself:

```
private float latestValidInputH;
private float latestValidInputV;

private void Update(){
    GetInput();
    Move();
}

private void GetInput(){
    float inputH = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float inputV = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    if(latestValidInputH == 0 || inputH == 0 || Mathf.Sign(inputH) == Mathf.Sign(latestValidInputH))
        latestValidInputH = inputH;
    if(latestValidInputV == 0 || inputV == 0 || Mathf.Sign(inputV) == Mathf.Sign(latestValidInputV))
        latestValidInputV = inputV;
}

private void Move() {
    _rb.velocity = new Vector2(latestValidInputH, latestValidInputV).normalized * speed;
}
```